# XPages: possible bug with enableModifiedFlag in Release 9.0.1FP3 HF241, and workaround

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a page where I wanted to use the "enableModifiedFlag" property, to let users know that their edit was not saved if they want to leave a page before saving.

I also have a search box in that page, and when I set the field to the static value "true", the message was popping because the search box was considered part of the page, and the field was modified.  This all makes sense.

Since the "enableModifiedFlag" property can be computed, I decieded to set it to true only if the document was in edit mode, as the search box is not available at that time.  The behaviour I got was that the message was not appearing anymore.  I then tested with returning true as the value of the property, and it didn't change anything: the message was just gone.  I then used the static values and set it to true, and the message was then appearing.

My conclusion is that there is a bug that prevents any computed value to be considered for that property.

So I had to find a workaround to prevent the message from popping up when users used the serach box.  Here is the solution I came up with.

On the client side, we have access to the XSP object.  One of its method is XSP._setDirty().  you can either set it to true or false, and it will affect if the page diplays the popup message or not.  So in my search button, I added this code on the onclick event, on the client side:

```
XSP._setDirty(false,""); //so we don't get the "do you want to leave this page" message
showStandBy();  //show standby in case search is long or slow
return true;
```

That way, I tell my page not to show the message and the popup is not displayed.

It's still a shame you can't use the computed value for that property, but at least we have a workaround.  Hope this will be useful to somebody!!!

GOT SOMETHING WORKING I THINK

This is what I have now, that controls teh flag:

```
<xp:this.enableModifiedFlag><![CDATA[${javascript:context.getUrlParameter("action")=="editDocument";}]]></xp:this.enableModifiedFlag>
```

I would rather use the document1.isEditable() function, but I wasn't successful with it so far, neither computed dynamically nor on page load.

At leaset I have something that seems to be working.  Time to submit that code to the end users!

Comment: Can you include the code you used to compute the property? Please include whether it's a dynamic binding (`#{...}`) or page load binding (`${...}`). It may be this cannot be computed dynamically or the edit needs a full reload of the page (assuming the behaviour has not changed since 8.5.3!)

Comment: Paul, I had this at one point, and it acted as if the property wasn't set at all: enableModifiedFlag="#{javascript:true}".  The ultimate goal would be to have it to true if the document is in edit mode and false if not.

Comment: I updated my question with a piece of code that seems to be working.  It's not quite the solution I wanted, but it seems to do what I need.